# Migrating springfox to springdoc-openapi-ui issue with annotations

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

Spring fox:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Gets the status for ID",
   consumes = "application/json",
   produces = "application/json",
   response = xyz.class)
```

Springdoc :

```
@Operation(summary = "Gets the status for ID",
   consumes = "application/json",
   produces = "application/json",
   response = xyz.class)
```

Here I'm able to replace `value` with `summary` but no idea what to use in place of `consumes`, `produces`, `response`  can anyone help?

I tried to use `@Tags` but it is not working. Could someone suggest a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used  @RouterOperation to resolve my issue

```
  @RouterOperation(operation = @Operation(summary = "Gets the status for ID"),
          consumes = "application/json",
          produces = "application/json",
          parameterTypes = xyz.class)
```

Comment: If you have solved your problem yourself, mark the answer as accepted to close the thread.

Comment: @M.Dudek I tried doing that but it says : "You can accept your own answer in 22 hours"